# Function that reads file in java

Tags: java, json, intellij-14

I am new to Java. I want to write a method that reads a file.
For example, in the main class, there is something like,

```
Car model = new CarImpl("default.json");
```

And in the Engine interface class, I want to write a function/method that reads the default.jason file, but I don't know how to do it.

What I did in the Engine interface class is:

```
public interface Car{
    public CarImpl (String files) {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(files);
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I do not see you reading and parsing the JSON file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood correctly you are try to create car and engine mapping with oops, However I could not able to find any code for engine interface in your implementation and interface dont have any constructor and provide the default implementation you can use java8 default method in interface please find code

```
interface Car {
default void defaultCarImpl(Engine e){
e.defaultEngineImpl();
} 

}

interface Engine{
default void defaultEngineImpl(){
//task
} 
}

class CarImp implements Car{

}

class EngineImpl implements Engine {
}
```

Note - Syntax not verified you can able find on google , main purpose to give understanding 
Please let me know if its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Interface shouldn't have any implementation generally unless it's a defender (default) method since Java 8. Read up on it. Think of interface as contract that needs to be adhered to.

You have this code at the top `new CarImpl("default.json");` are you trying to create an instance of method inside a class or you have another concrete class that implements your car interface? You can read up a bit on interface [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-java/). Many other resources available online.

I think you will greatly benefit by reading up on thinking in an object oriented way. There are plenty of books and resources available to read up on. Some more concepts [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-oriented-programming-oops-concept-in-java/).

Comment: I am getting confused with this line:
    Car model = new CarImpl("default.json");
Doesnt it have to be
    Car mdel = new Car("default.jason");?